# About faithful representation of a finite-dimensional C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I know every C$^*$-algebra has a faithful representation on a Hilbert space. A representation of A is a $*$-homomorphism $\Phi: A \rightarrow B(H) $ for some Hilbert space $H$. Is there any special case when $A$ is a finite dimensional C$^*$-algebra, we cannot find a faithful representation of $A$ on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is finite-dimensional, doing GNS with a faithful state (the normalized trace, for instance) will give a faithful representation $\Phi:A\to B(H_0)$, with $H_0$ finite-dimensional. Now let $H=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}H_0,$ and define $\Phi_\infty:A\to B(H)$ by 
$$
\Phi_\infty(a)=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}\Phi(a).
$$
Then $\Phi_\infty$ is a faithful representation of $A$ on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Could you please recommend some lecture notes or a book with more detail about representation and GNS construction? I am reading this topic on my own and I am not so much familiar with functional analysis.

Comment: Murphy and Davidson would be the natural choices for me.

Comment: I read about GNS in the book by Kehe Zhu, but if the state be faithful, in a linear finite dimensional then ker is zero, so the ideal which we started to build the construction on that will be zero, where did I make mistake? Should I use another method?

Comment: Linear does not mean multiplicative. As I said in the answer, the trace is a faithful functional.

Comment: But if f is the state and $ f(xx*)=0,$ then if f is one to one, then $ xx*=0$ then it means $\|x\|=0$, so x becomes zero.so the ideal  $l_\phi=\{x \in A  \| f(xx*)=0\}$ is trivial, and the Hilbert space becomes $H= \frac{A}{l_\phi}$ becomes A.

Comment: Yes, of course. When do go GNS for the trace (or any other faithful state, for that matter) on $M_n(\mathbb C)$, the Hilbert space you get is again $M_n(\mathbb C)$, with the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\text{Tr}(B^*A)$. What's the problem?

Comment: So every finite dimensional C*algebra becomes a pre-Hilbert space. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) And actually, a Hilbert space (not "pre"): every finite-dimensional vector space is closed.

Comment: What does it mean for the trace (of a matrix) to be a faithful functional?

Comment: My bad. What I meant is that it is nonzero on all nonzero positive elements.